# Java: Class not found in Unix

Tags: java, unix, compilation

am trying to run a Java file on Unix machine. Let me show the directory structure first:

```
/home/username
  |_ SimpleMail.java
  |_ mail.jar
```

I have compiled the java code using:

```
# javac -classpath mail.jar SimpleMail.java
```

After compiling that, directory has:

```
/home/username
      |_ SimpleMail.java
      |_ mail.jar
      |_ SimpleMail.class
```

Now I tried to run that SimpleMail class file. That is giving Class not found error:
I have tried to run the class using:

```
# java -classpath mail.jar SimpleMail
```

Error:

```
The java class is not found:  SimpleMail
```

Whats wrong in that process?

Thanks :)

Comment: A nicely formatted and well presented question +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the current directory on the classpath too, in order to pick up the classfile there:

```
java -classpath mail.jar:. SimpleMail
```

That will work if `SimpleMail` isn't in a package. Otherwise you should compile with `-d .` and include the package name when you're running `java`:

```
javac -d . -classpath mail.jar SimpleMail.java

java -classpath mail.jar:. my.pkg.SimpleMail
```

Comment: @Mohamed: You need activation.jar. It should have been in the JavaMail distribution or linked to from it.

Comment: I have added that too, but now: java -classpath mail.jar:activation.jar:. SimpleMail            Waiting for very long time no response. What could be the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

```
# java -classpath mail.jar;. SimpleMail
```

will do